Selecting default item for collectionview
I'm seeking help with selecting a default item from the ItemsSource of a CollectionView. In the constructor, I populate the data list and set a specific item as the default by assigning it to SelectedTask. However, although SelectedTask is assigned correctly, nothing is reflected in the UI. When I click on CheckItem button in the command the SelectedItem, it's null. But if I manually select an item in the CollectionView, it correctly updates and is displayed in the UI. What am I doing wrong with setting the default selection in my Maui app?
   public partial class NewPage1ViewModel : ObservableObject
   {
       public ObservableCollection<TaskItem> Tasks { get; }

       [ObservableProperty]
       TaskItem _selectedTask;

       public NewPage1ViewModel()
       {
           Tasks = new ObservableCollection<TaskItem>
           {
               new TaskItem { Name = "Task 1", Deadline = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1) },
               new TaskItem { Name = "Task 2", Deadline = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2) },
               new TaskItem { Name = "Task 3", Deadline = DateTime.Now.AddDays(3) },
               new TaskItem { Name = "Task 4", Deadline = DateTime.Now.AddDays(4) },
           };

           // Here SelectedTask is not null its set to value correctly.
           SelectedTask = Tasks.FirstOrDefault(); // or Tasks[2]
       }

       [RelayCommand]
       private void CheckItem()
       {
           // Here SelectedTask is always null
           if (SelectedTask is null)
           {
               Debug.WriteLine("selected item is null");
           }
       }
   }

   public class TaskItem
   {
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public DateTime Deadline { get; set; }
   }

And the Page itself:
<VerticalStackLayout>
    <Button Command="{Binding CheckItemCommand}" Text="Check item" />
    <Label
        Margin="0,20,0,0"
        FontSize="Medium"
        Text="Selected Task:" />
    <Label
        FontAttributes="Bold"
        FontSize="Large"
        Text="{Binding SelectedTask.Name}" />
    <Label
        FontAttributes="Bold"
        FontSize="Large"
        Text="{Binding SelectedTask.Deadline, StringFormat='{}{0:MM/dd/yyyy}'}" />

    <StackLayout Padding="10">
        <Label FontSize="Large" Text="Tasks" />

        <CollectionView
            ItemsSource="{Binding Tasks}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTask}"
            SelectionMode="Single">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout Padding="10" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Label FontSize="Medium" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        <Label
                            FontSize="Medium"
                            HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                            Text="{Binding Deadline, StringFormat='{}{0:MM/dd/yyyy}'}" />

                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState Name="Normal" />
                                <VisualState Name="Selected">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="LightSkyBlue" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>

                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>

    </StackLayout>
</VerticalStackLayout>


However, although SelectedTask is assigned correctly, nothing is reflected in the UI. When I click on CheckItem button in the command the SelectedItem, it's null.   Based on the code you shared, I did a test on my side, but I couldn't reproduce this problem. Could you please post the steps of reproducing this problem so that we can try to reproduce this problem on our side?

Add a breakpoint to the end of the constructor after SelectedTask is set to one of the item from the list First or any [n]. (For me here SelectedTask is set correctly when i check with debug). After the app appears, even I set the SelectedTask in the constructor I can not see on the Ui at all. I added the button and in the command i check if SelectedTask is null for me always null even I set it in the constructor. (my goal is select any item by default without selecting manually.) - updated the code

Perhaps (1) you would like to may your SelectedItem binding TwoWay, (2) the CollectionView always initializes it's SelectedItem during construction, so, it will definitely not receive values from your incoming view model, to remedy this, you will need to delay your default initialization.

I tried to add the initial value setup SelectedTask = Tasks[1] in the OnAppearing after a Task.Delay(500) it is the same still.

After the app appears, even I set the SelectedTask in the constructor I can not see on the Ui at all.  According to the steps you say, I could see the SelectedTask could display normally on my android emulator.  What device are you testing on and what is the version? You can also try to update your visual studio to the latest one.

Have you checked this issue Custom selection styles for items in CollectionView are ignored when programmatically selecting an item

In the end I solved with adding IsSelected flag to the ItemViewModel and apply conditional styling, with this way initial selection also working
